# Python `pip install` from a local project - Modules can't find each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, python-module

I have a development server running in `virtualenv` (Python 3.6), into which I want to install a local python project. If I run `pip install -e /path/to/myproject` while `virtualenv` is active, then inside that environment I can `import myproject`. I can also do `from myproject import submodule`. But if I do `from myproject import othermodule`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodule'.` (`othermodule` imports `submodule`). This does not happen if I `import myproject` from `myproject`'s root.

The directory structure is:

```
/path/to/myproject
    setup.py
    myproject/
        __init__.py
        submodule.py
        othermodule.py
        ...
```

`setup.py` looks like:

```
setup(
name='myproject'
packages=['myproject']
)
```

What's going on? Why aren't those libraries found?

Comment: What's in `submodule` and `othermodule`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The relevant info is that `othermodule` imports `submodule` (and not vice versa). Beyond that, there is quite a lot of code. Do you need to know something specific?

Comment: How exactly does `othermodule` import `submodule`? Please show the `import` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that Python 3 relative imports must be explicit.

In `othermodule`, instead of

```
import submodule
```

I need to write:

```
import myproject.submodule
```

or

```
import .submodule
```